# Toast with image background

Tags: java, android

I have this simple code that brings me a toast with an image. Is it possible to have the background that the regular toast uses on this toast?

Thx in advance

```
        Toast ImageToast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
        LinearLayout toastLayout = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
        toastLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
        TextView text = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.smile);
        text.setTextSize(30);
        text.setText("Show this text");
        toastLayout.addView(image);
        toastLayout.addView(text);
        ImageToast.setView(toastLayout);
        ImageToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        ImageToast.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a full custom layout as is mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView)

Answer (score 0):

Check this questions:
[Adding image to Toast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571917/adding-image-to-toast) 
[Toast background changing to match Activity's Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020286/toast-background-changing-to-match-activitys-theme) 
Also it's good idea to check that:
http://www.cmwmobile.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6&Itemid=40