# show an image in a toast

Tags: android, toast

I have used **toasts** in my **android** projects to display **text**. Can I use **toasts** to display an **image** popup message. If so can someone give me some useful code segment. Thank You!

Comment: You could create a custom dialog and use animation to make it appear in a faded motion just like a toast

Comment: http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-custom-toast.html Check that one out.

Comment: yep. I can use a custom dialog. But what i need is the message should disappear in a short time as a toast. can I do that with a custom dialog.

Comment: refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571917/adding-image-to-toast

Answer (score 1):

You can see my sample code via this link:
https://github.com/Hesamedin/CustomToast

The most important class is [this class](https://github.com/Hesamedin/CustomToast/blob/master/src/com/kamalan/widget/MyToast.java) which drived from Toast class and modified it.

Then use it in normal way as Toast usage like this:

```
btnCustomToast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCustomToast);
        btnCustomToast.setTypeface(pacificoFont);
        btnCustomToast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is custom toast message.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

As I commented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571917/adding-image-to-toast) post you can use my [SuperToasts](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts) library if you do not feel like creating your own Toast View. You can easily display an image with the following code:

```
 SuperToast superToast = new SuperToast(getActivity());  
 superToast.setDuration(SuperToast.DURATION_LONG); 
 superToast.setText("Hello world!");  
 superToast.setIconResource(R.drawable.image, SuperToast.IconPosition.LEFT);
 superToast.show();
```

The library also comes with a bunch of icons already made and has a bunch of configurable options such as animations, backgrounds, text colors etc. Alternatively you can use [SuperActivityToasts](https://github.com/JohnPersano/Supertoasts/wiki/SuperActivityToast) if you need to use a Toast within an Activity which will give you access to clickable buttons, progress bars, dismiss listeners etc.

Comment: oops ! I got some problem. When I use a SuperToast inside a fragment the app got stop. what's the reason for this and how can I fix it.

Comment: You have to use an Activity Context for the SuperActivityToast. What's the stacktrace say?

Comment: @JohnP. I can't seem to find a `setView` method like normal Toasts support? How can I set a custom layout file as the view?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do with toast

Code:Add this in your code part

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.like_popup, (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.like_popup_layout));
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.like_popup_iv);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_delete_icon);

Toast toast = new Toast(activity.getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 200);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Design:like_popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cred_menu_like_popup_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/customshapetransparent"
    android:paddingTop="35dp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/like_popup_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Design: customshapetransparent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <solid android:color="#60000000" />  
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Hope this will give you what you want to achive