# Where is @drawable/new_logo defined?

Tags: java, android

I see in a project 
`android:src="@drawable/new_logo"/>` but I can not see where this `new_logo` is defined. By googling I see this pattern in other examples e.g. [add image to toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571917/adding-image-to-toast) in the accepted answer.
What is this new_logo? I tried to copy paste this to a new project but I get:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src'
>   with value '@drawable/  new_logo').

Also:

> Failed to convert @drawable/new_logo into a drawable

Why it hits an error? I tried to grep the files of the project that seems to work but I could not find a file new_logo but there is no error at that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see in a project android:src="@drawable/new_logo"/> but I can not see where this new_logo is defined.

It will be a file in either a `res/drawable.../` directory or a `res/mipmap.../` directory in your project. Probably the file is a PNG file, though it could be something else.

> Why it hits an error?

Because you do not have a drawable resource with that name.