# How to display "Registered Successfull" Message in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Any one can tell me how to display this Message in Android.
Registered Successfully
[Click To view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahbwm.png)

Comment: Read about Android Toast and setting custom layout for toast - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should use a custom Toast.

Create a layout resource file. My resource file is named toast.xml, but name it whatever you want. Find an image of the green check, and save it to your app's drawable folder.

toast.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toast_layout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#FFF" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
    android:contentDescription="Green check mark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/green_check_mark"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FF8B8B8B"
    android:text="Registered Successfully"/>
```

In your MainActivity.java

```
public void showCustomToast(String message) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(message);
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
}
```

Just call `showCustomToast("Registered Successfully)` to show the Toast. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The class used to display temporary messages in android is called `Toast`.

The method to display a toast is as follows :-

```
Toast.makeText(context,"Your message to display",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Read up more on `Toast` here [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html). And to add images and customise the toast ( as shown in your image ) , you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7578806/7626492).